# Django EmailMultiAlternatives safe tag problem in html version

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to pass urls with safe tag in my emails, but it seems like Django ignores it. I'm using Django==4.1.6

I have the next code for email sending:

```
from config.celery_app import app
from smtplib import SMTPException
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import mark_safe


@app.task(autoretry_for=(SMTPException,))
def user_created(context, send_to):
    email_html_message = render_to_string("email/activation_email.html", context)
    email_plaintext_message = render_to_string("email/activation_email.txt", context)
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        # title:
        "Please confirm your registration in {title}".format(
            title=settings.PROJECT_NAME
        ),
        # message:
        email_plaintext_message,
        # from:
        from_email,
        # to:
        send_to,
    )
    msg.attach_alternative(mark_safe(email_html_message), "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

This is "**email/activation_email.html**":

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{activate_url|safe}}">{{activate_url|safe}}</a>
```

And this is "**email/activation_email.txt**":

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hello {{ name }},

Please click on the link to confirm your registration:

{{activate_url|safe}}

{% endautoescape %}
```

In email/activation_email.txt I have working activate_url like "*http://localhost:8000/activate-account?token=bmviz3-14727ab7a3e4946117f9efa98ab03ea1&uid=MTZjY2E5MjMtNjNhYi00YzhkLTg0MTEtMjIwZTI0MGNlNGZj*"

But in HTML variant of email I have wrong url like "*http://localhost:8000/activate-account?token=3Dbmviz3-14727ab7a3e4946117f9efa98ab03ea1&uid=3DMTZjY2E5MjMtNjNhYi00YzhkLTg0MTEtMjIwZTI0MGNlNGZj*"

What's happens with my urls in HTML template? Why they are different? Under **activate_url** I have: "*http://localhost:8000/activate-account?token=bmviz3-14727ab7a3e4946117f9efa98ab03ea1&uid=MTZjY2E5MjMtNjNhYi00YzhkLTg0MTEtMjIwZTI0MGNlNGZj*"